# Auto-refresh/ Auto-reload assets

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, ring

I'm new to clojure and i'm having a hard time figuring out how to reload/ refresh the browser when changes have been made to either html/ js/ css etc.

this is my current setup *project.clj*

```
(defproject app2 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://exampl.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.89"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.5.0"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.5.0"]
                 [enfocus "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.3"]
            [lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-paths ["src/cljs"],
                        :compiler {
                          :main "scripts.client"
                          :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                          :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                          :asset-path "js/out"
                          ;;:pretty-print true
                          ;;:optimizations :none
                          }}]}
  :main app2.server/app
  :ring {:handler app2.server/app :auto-reload? true :auto-refresh? true :reload-paths ["src" "resources"]}
  :profiles {
    :dev {
            :ring {
              :nrepl {
                :start? true
                :port 9000
              }
            }
          }
   }
  )
```

This is my *server.clj*

```
(ns app2.server
  (:use [ring.middleware.resource :only [wrap-resource]]
        [ring.middleware.file-info :only [wrap-file-info]]
        [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]])

        ;;(:require app2.repl)
)


(defn handler
    [request]
    {:status 200}

  )

;handling routing "/" -> "/index.html"
(defn wrap-index [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (println (pr-str req))
    (if (= (:uri req) "/")
      (handler (assoc req :uri "/index.html"))
      (handler req))))

;setting up a simple resource handler for ring
(def app (-> handler
             (wrap-resource "public")
             (wrap-file-info)
             (wrap-index)
             (wrap-reload app {:dirs ["src" "resources"]})
             ))
```

How can this be accomplished?

I'm used to developing in node and you have tools like browser sync, weinre and supervisor. What are the equivalents in clojure?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel), which lets you do *hot reloading* of your ClojureScript and CSS in the browser.

There is of course not one good way of setting up your build, but my way to go for languages like SASS etc. is to watch and compile them as a separate process, and have Figwheel watch the generated CSS.

For example, on one of my ClojureScript projects, I had a script file for LESS compilation which used the LESS compiler and the [wr](https://github.com/pmuellr/wr) utility directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
lessc src/styles/main.main.less resources/public/css/main.css --source-map && cp src/styles/*.less resources/public/css
wr "lessc src/styles/main.main.less resources/public/css/main.css --source-map && cp src/styles/*.less resources/public/css" src/**/*.less
```

Of course you can also use things like Gulp, Webpack - or any tool you're used to.

The alternative is to use Leiningen plugins, see the list [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins).